# Action required to handle invalid UTF-8 bytes

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, utf-8, utf-16

We are facing issue which identified from event log of application, this error is not reproducible. Error is something like this:

`System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://WebsiteName/:genUpdateObj. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type NameSpaceName.RequestClassName. 'ڵj��d�f�' contains invalid UTF8 bytes.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an error deserializing the object of type  NameSpacName.ClassName. 'ڵj��d�f�' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: 'ڵj��d�f�' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ---> System.Text.DecoderFallbackException: Unable to translate bytes [FC] at index 3 from specified code page to Unicode.`

This is error while de-serialization of request object into class object for WCF service contract method. We have WCF operational contract like this:

```
public ResponseClass MethodName(RequestClassName genUpdateObj)
{
    //Service operations
}
```

Looks like one of `string` property of class `RequestClassName` having invalid UTF-8 characters.
I need some help to initiate some good preventive code mechanism in our server side WCF services.

Comment: Did you some custom serialization? What is the real class-name behind this cryptic chars?

Comment: No we do not have any custom serialization, request class name is `MachineUpdate` having string property `MachineName`, this property does contains some invalid UTF-8 charset. Those character I have added in exception message, I think `?` replaced for invalid characters.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "this property does contains some invalid UTF-8 charset"? If you've got a string object at the server side, you should find out exactly what is in it.

Comment: @JonSkeet No we dont have request object, that might not true but looking at exception that can only I predict. What would be possible issue and solution?

Comment: I really don't know, but I would start by adding logging into the server side if you possibly can.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes we are updating our server for event log to support Unicode characters that is only action we can do now.